# How to reverse proxy https with lighttpd?

Tags: reverse-proxy, https, lighttpd, forwarding

I want to forward (reverse proxy) requests to **https://secure.mydomain.com(:443)** to my internal (HTTPS-)WebServer on port 8443 using Lighttp.

**Environment-Infos:**
My WebServer is a Tomcat running on Port 8080 (HTTP) and Port 8443 (HTTPS).
HTTP and HTTPs works well when accessing it locally (http://127.0.0.1:8080 and/or https://127.0.0.1:8443)

(Port 8080 + Port 8443 are not direct reachable over the Internet.)

For **HTTP**, this config works:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "unsecure.mydomain.com" {
    proxy.server  = ( "" => ( (
            "host" => "127.0.0.1",
            "port" => 8080
    ) ) )
}
```

**Question:**
What is needed to reverse-proxy **HTTPS**?

Answer (score 2):

lighttpd doesn't support TLS on backend connections.

If the backend needs to know whether the frontend connection was made with TLS check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

If you need an encrypted connection to the backend (due to an untrusted network), use a VPN.

If you wanted end-to-end encryption to the backend you need a TCP proxy (haproxy can route connections based on [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)), or just forward it with iptables and DNAT.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer; haproxy is a very useful tool and I used it to forward a https server to internet (I just used tcp ssl pass-trough). Thanks for pointing it out